# Search a user from sqlite database and give him permission to login?

Tags: android

I am new to android development and i have created a database that is working right. but when i want to search a user from that db my app stops working. i have created three classes one for create and that is working correctly and one to access db to get login to user and one databasehelper class

this is my databaseHelper code

```
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;


public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1;
private static final String DATABASE_NAME="USER.db";
private static final String TABLE_NAME="USER";
private static final String COL_1="ID";
private static final String COL_2="NAME";
private static final String COL_3="EMAIL";
private static final String COL_4="PASS";
SQLiteDatabase db;



public DatabaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME , null , DATABASE_VERSION );
}


@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL("create table " + TABLE_NAME + " (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, NAME TEXT, EMAIL TEXT, PASS TEXT)");

}
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXIST "+TABLE_NAME);
    onCreate(db);

}
public void insertData(String name, String email, String pass)
{
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values=new ContentValues();
    ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
    contentValues.put(COL_3,email);
    contentValues.put(COL_4, pass);
   // long result=
    db.insert(TABLE_NAME, null, contentValues);
    //if (result==-1)
      //  return false;
    //else
      //  return true;
    db.close();
}
public String searchUser(String email){
    SQLiteDatabase db=this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("select * from "+TABLE_NAME, null);
    String a, b;
    b = "not found";
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            a = cursor.getString(0);

            if (a.equals(email)) {
                b = cursor.getString(1);
                break;
            }
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());

    }
    return b;

}
```

}

and this is Login Class from which i want to access a database

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {
EditText  editpassword, editemail;
TextView linkRegister;
Button buttonRegister;
DatabaseHelper myDB;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    editemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_email);
    editpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_password);
    linkRegister=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.LinkRegister);
    buttonRegister=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ButtonSignin);

    buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(this);
    linkRegister.setOnClickListener(this);



}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId())
    {
        case R.id.LinkRegister:
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));
            break;
        case R.id.ButtonSignin:
            //Toast mess = Toast.makeText(Login.this, "username and password don't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
            //mess.show();
            String email=editemail.getText().toString();
            String password=editpassword.getText().toString();
            String dbpassword=myDB.searchUser(email);
            if(password.equals(dbpassword))
            {
                Toast mess = Toast.makeText(Login.this, "username and password matched", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                mess.show();

            }
            else{
                Toast msg = Toast.makeText(Login.this, "username and password don't match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                msg.show();
            }
           // startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, NewsFeed.class));
            break;

    }

}
```

}

this is my Logcat

```
02-09 17:22:15.321 18955-18955/? D/dalvikvm: Late-enabling CheckJNI
02-09 17:22:15.491 18955-18955/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)
02-09 17:22:15.491 18955-18955/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onSearchRequested, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onSearchRequested
02-09 17:22:15.491 18955-18955/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17969: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onSearchRequested (Landroid/view/SearchEvent;)Z
02-09 17:22:15.491 18955-18955/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-09 17:22:15.491 18955-18955/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.view.Window$Callback.onWindowStartingActionMode, referenced from method android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onWindowStartingActionMode 
02-09 17:22:15.491 18955-18955/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve interface method 17973: Landroid/view/Window$Callback;.onWindowStartingActionMode (Landroid/view/ActionMode$Callback;I)Landroid/view/ActionMode;
02-09 17:22:15.491 18955-18955/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x72 at 0x0002
02-09 17:22:15.591 18955-18955/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getChangingConfigurations, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getChangingConfigurations
02-09 17:22:15.591 18955-18955/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 424: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getChangingConfigurations ()I
02-09 17:22:15.591 18955-18955/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-09 17:22:15.591 18955-18955/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.getType, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.TintTypedArray.getType
02-09 17:22:15.591 18955-18955/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 446: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.getType (I)I
02-09 17:22:15.591 18955-18955/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-09 17:22:15.641 18955-18955/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawable
02-09 17:22:15.641 18955-18955/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 387: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawable (ILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-09 17:22:15.641 18955-18955/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-09 17:22:15.641 18955-18955/? I/dalvikvm: Could not find method android.content.res.Resources.getDrawableForDensity, referenced from method android.support.v7.widget.ResourcesWrapper.getDrawableForDensity
02-09 17:22:15.641 18955-18955/? W/dalvikvm: VFY: unable to resolve virtual method 389: Landroid/content/res/Resources;.getDrawableForDensity (IILandroid/content/res/Resources$Theme;)Landroid/graphics/drawable/Drawable;
02-09 17:22:15.641 18955-18955/? D/dalvikvm: VFY: replacing opcode 0x6e at 0x0002
02-09 17:22:15.781 18955-18955/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Enabling debug mode 0
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41631c08)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.mubbasher.howdy, PID: 18955
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.mubbasher.howdy.Login.onClick(Login.java:48)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4661)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19498)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5641)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1288)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1104)
02-09 17:22:33.721 18955-18955/com.example.mubbasher.howdy E/AndroidRuntime:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: where is your logcat? post it. based on your code `myDB = null` so i think that's an issue

Comment: Post logcat, so that we can trace your crash

Comment: Also why do you do a = cursor.getString(0); and then compare it with email? Column 0 is the ID column and you should do int x = cursor.getInt(0) and this will give you id.

Comment: Now i add a=cusor.getString(2); and that is email in db and compared it with email but nothing searched @DalmaRacz

Comment: thanks @DalmaRacz its working now

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to initialize myDB in your Login class.

Write Below line in your onCreate() method of Login Class.

```
 DatabaseHelper myDB;
 myDB=new DatabaseHelper(LoginActivity.this);
```

Comment: Have you changed your query for search functionality ?